# Is it possible to correct the display of the model in the format GLTF or GLB in Three.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, gltf

Initially, the model was completely black, on the Internet they mainly said that the problem was in the light, but the light does not affect my model at all, in the end the only thing I found was to fix the model itself with the **traverse** function

```
function loadModel(modelIndex) {
    const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    loader.load(models[modelIndex], (gltf) => {
        gltf.scene.traverse((child) => {
            if (child.isMesh) {
                child.material.emissive =  child.material.color;
                child.material.emissiveMap = child.material.map;
            }
        });
        scene.clear();
        scene.add(gltf.scene);
        gltf.scene.rotation.y = Math.PI * -0.75;
    });
}
```

- This is what the model looks like now: [my model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9VnR.png)
- This is what the model should roughly look like: [model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dl2zP.png)

I tried changing both the color and light for the model, but it didn't change anything for me

1. Imports:

```
import {OrbitControls} from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";
import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.128.0/examples/js/loaders/FBXLoader.js";
import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.138.0/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";
```

2. Scene:

```
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
```

3. Camera:

```
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 2000);
```

4. Render:

```
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
document.getElementById('modelContainer').appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

5. Control:

```
const control = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
control.enableDamping = true;
control.minDistance = 4;
```

6. Light:

```
const ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 1)
scene.add(ambient);

let light1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1);
light1.position.set(0,450,500);
scene.add(light1);

let light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1);
light2.position.set(500,100,50);
scene.add(light2);
```

7. Model loading and animation function:

```
const models = [
    './models/bmw/scene.gltf',
];

let currentModelIndex = 0;

function loadModel(modelIndex) {
    const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    loader.load(models[modelIndex], (gltf) => {
        gltf.scene.traverse((child) => {
            if (child.isMesh) {
                child.material.emissive =  child.material.color;
                child.material.emissiveMap = child.material.map;
            }
        });
        scene.clear();
        scene.add(gltf.scene);
        gltf.scene.rotation.y = Math.PI * -0.75;

    });
}

document.getElementById('nextModel').addEventListener('click', () => {
    currentModelIndex = (currentModelIndex + 1) % models.length;
    loadModel(currentModelIndex);
});

camera.position.z = 5;

function animate() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    control.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

loadModel(currentModelIndex);
animate();
```

8. **HTML** code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Models</title>
    <style>
        body {
                margin: 0;
        }
        canvas {
                display: block;
        }
        #buttonContainer {
            position: absolute;

            top: 5%;
            left: 45%;
            z-index: 1;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="buttonContainer">
        <button id="nextModel">Next model</button>
    </div>
    <div id="modelContainer"></div>

    <script src="three.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For something to appear metallic and reflective, it must have something to reflect. The current lights don't provide that. The best option is to use an environment map as shown in this example: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_car

Answer (score 0):

Try positioning lights in various way, but I assume you tried already...
I remember either I had similar issue with textures, in my case converting to glb, fixed that, try, maybe help you as well.
And try this one as well:

```
function loadModel(modelIndex) {
    const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    loader.load(models[modelIndex], (gltf) => {
        gltf.scene.traverse((child) => {
            if (child.isMesh) {
                // Chek if the material has a map before accessing it
                if (child.material.map) {
                    child.material.emissive = child.material.color;
                    child.material.emissiveMap = child.material.map;
                }
            }
        });
        scene.clear();
        scene.add(gltf.scene);
        gltf.scene.rotation.y = Math.PI * -0.75;
    });
}
```